# Bugs / Design issues on the Stack Overflow Research / Learn More page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon, research

On the [learn more](http://business.stackoverflow.com/research/learn-more) page linked from the [research](https://stackoverflow.com/research) page, there are a few bugs.

1. In the contact field, some have `-` before and after (e.g. `- Job Title -`) and others don't. This doesn't seem to signify anything.
2. The *"- How many developers do you plan to hire in the next 12 months -"* is cut off before you open the dropdown. Also, the HTML / CSS for that all says "3 months" not "12 months".

   [image]
3. The favicon is different to the main site, and the Research site (it has a white background).

Comment: Sigh, dark grey text on a black background. Is my complete inability to read any of that just a sign of me being old?

Comment: @theB The text is quite dark... Good point.

Comment: It's a bit better on my large high DPI desktop screen, but on my mobile screen, its completely invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Investigated a few things:

- We've updated the fields here to be more consistent with dashes where the dropdowns are.
- We're okay with the cutoff on the dropdown for how many developers since it becomes visible upon click.
- We'll also look into making the favicon consistent across both sites, but have to do that in the future.